# Azure Logic App throwing 302 Redirect Error

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I am getting redirect 302 error for my HTTP request in my logic app.

The scenario is that I have a logic app where I want to fetch data from an API endpoint. The API endpoint is protected and I need to provide an access token to be able to access the api.

To be able to connect to the API with an access token I have created an service principal in Azure AD (spn) to use in the logic app.

The logic app contains right now of two HTTP actions:

- The first HTTP action makes a request against `https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantId>/oauth2/token`

with client_id, client_secret and tenant_id of the service principal to get an access token which I can use to authenticate against the API.

- The second HTTP action makes a request against the API endpoint
- with Header 
  Authroization = Bearer

but I only get 302 Redirect as response.

I have verified that everything is working as expected with Postman with the same requests as explained above.

Any ideas on how to get around this issue?

[Redirect screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pBk7.png)

[Logic App workflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7woCu.png)

Comment: Could you add some screenshots?

Comment: I could for sure add some screenshots, however they will not provide any information that is not already provided in the above text.

Comment: the redirect is the result of 2 possible scenarios: 1- the token is expired and your api sends a "redirect" in order to get a new one; 2-the process to acquire the token is redirecting you to Azure AD login page. It's not clear which of those two possible scenarios is happening.

Comment: By the likes of it seems to be a ms api?? The reason I asked for screenshots is that I have developed logic apps that use the client credentials  flow to seek authorization to apis and they have not thrown redirect errors. Hence I was wondering if this was api specific behavior in logic apps?

Comment: It seems odd if the token has expired, the first HTTP action does a GET request to retrieve a bearer token which is then passed on to the next step. 

The API is also located on-prem and I've configured an Application Proxy to be able to make requests from outside of the local network.

Comment: The ideal way of consuming on Prem apis in logic apps is through the on premises data gateway ,I am not sure just extending the proxy would work.  Can you please share what is the redirect url you get in the location header ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the cause of this issue. It was in fact something wrong with the token, the logic app successfully acquired the Bearer token, however, However, in the POST request against : https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/oauth2/token

I had specified the following:

```
grant_type=client_credentials
&client_id=<clientId>
&client_secret=<clientSecret>
&resource=https://something.com <- (HERE I forgot an "/")
```

I found this when I tried using the token aquired in the logic app in postman and it returned a redirect and invalid token.
Thanks for the help all.